# Landscape mode UI in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, storyboard

For my iPad application, I am using storyboard and want my UI to adjust both in portrait and landscape modes properly. My UI go for a toss in landscape mode. Is there any way we can fix this from storyboard?

I want to keep both Portrait and Landscape modes.

Comment: Have you tried using auto layout and constraints?

Comment: I have never used auto layout and constraints. Could you please point me to a good documentation for that.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2. This is a GREAT place to start. Make sure you go through both parts and it should give you a nice understanding of auto layout. Good luck

Comment: Thank you. It helped and I was able to fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

use auto layouts and constraints in your storyboard. and constraints to support both landscape and portrait mode.

some tutorials are :
http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1[tutorial1]

http://captechconsulting.com/blog/jack-cox/ios-7-tutorial-series-auto-layout-xcode-5[tutorials2]